# How is it possible to get top comment from all children?

Tags: query

I'm able to check whether or not the parent comment is the top comment:

```
$comment_obj = get_comment( $comment_ID );
$parent_ID = $comment_obj->comment_parent;
```

But I'd like to be able to get the top comment no matter if I am posting a child or grandchild etc. I can't find much information of retrieving parent/top comments at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adapt `get_post_acestors()`, and write a similar function for comments. Here is an example that returns the top comment's id or `false`. *Not tested!*

```
function get_root_comment( $comment_id ) {
    
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );  
 
    if ( ! $comment 
        || empty( $comment->comment_parent ) 
        || $comment->comment_parent == $comment_id 
    ) {
        return false;
    }
 
    $ancestors   = [];   
    $id          = $comment->comment_parent;
    $ancestors[] = $id;
 
    while ( $ancestor = get_comment( $id ) ) {
        
        if ( empty ( $ancestor->comment_parent ) ) {
            return $id;
        }
        
        // self-reference
        if ( $ancestor->comment_parent == $id ) {
            return $id;
        }
        
        // loop
        if ( in_array( $ancestor->comment_parent, $ancestors, true ) ) {
            return $id;
        }
 
        $id          = $ancestor->comment_parent;
        $ancestors[] = $id;
    }
}
```

Usage in other code with a `WP_Comment` object:

```
$root_comment = get_root_comment( $comment_obj->comment_ID );

if ( $root_comment ) {
    // do something with the ID
}
```

Comment: Thanks fuxia! How might I use this within a pre-existing function? For example, this would be a small variable within a function, but I want to include the final '$id' within an array

Comment: I have edited my original question and added my current code. You'll be able to see where I want to implement the comment parent ID.

Comment: @DarrylSyms I have added an usage example.

Comment: Thanks @fuxia! I appreciate your time and clarification. However, I can't seem to get it to work. I placed `$root_comment = get_root_comment( $comment_obj->comment_ID );` into my previous function, and then try to include `$root_comment` in the array, but it returns a 500 error. If you've any clues on why this might be the case, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: 500 means usually a syntax error. [Turn debugging on](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/), and try to get some deatils.